# How do I translate this description of the Spanish Queen's dress style? 西班牙王后做造型真省事：连续两年裙子配饰完全不变参加同一活动

Tags: translation

The title of [this article](https://baijiahao.baidu.com/s?id=1655071922698776028&wfr=spider&for=pc) about the Spanish Queen [Letizia Ortiz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queen_Letizia_of_Spain)'s dress style is:

> 西班牙王后做造型真省事：连续两年裙子配饰完全不变参加同一活动

To give a mental picture, here's a reduced-quality image from that article:

[image]

Breaking the title apart, we have:

> Spain [西班牙] queen [王后] (???) [做] appearance (?) [造型] really [真] simplifies matters [省事]: [for] two years [两年] in a row [连续] dress [裙子] and accessories [配饰] completely [完全] unvarying [不变], participating in [参加] the same [同一] (???) activities [活动].

So my rough approximation is:

> Spain's queen appearance is really simplistic: for two years in a row, her dress and accessories are completely unvarying, and she participates in the same activities

I'm a bit worried about a few grammar points here: (a) I don't see what 做 is doing, (b) I'm not sure if 不变 applies to her dress and accessories, or her activities.  Also the article is dated 2012, whereas Wikipedia says she was coronated 19 June 2014.  So it's possible I misunderstand 王后 too.

**Question**: How do I translate this description of the Spanish Queen's dress style?

Comment: 省事：save trouble；连续：continuously；

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Literally, 做：do; 造型：mould, model, style;

做造型 in the context means *the style she dressed herself*.

不变 applies to her dress and accessories.

A rough translation:

> 西班牙王后做造型真省事: ***The style the Spanish queen dressed herself is really
>   simplistic.***
>
> 连续两年裙子配饰完全不变参加同一活动: ***For two years in a row, she participated in the
>   same activities with her dress and accessories completely
>   unvarying.***

Answer (score 1):

> (a) I don't see what 做 is doing

做造型 means to prepare her appearance. It is eligible to use in this way.

> I'm not sure if 不变 applies to her dress and accessories, or her
>   activities.

不变 applies to her dress and accessories not her activities.

> How do I translate this description of the Spanish Queen's dress
>   style?

Queen really saved her effort of preparing her appearance, she attended the annual event with the same dress and accessories two years in a row.

Answer (score 1):

西班牙王后做造型真省事：连续两年裙子配饰完全不变参加同一活动

做造型：function as a (role) model

The Spanish Queen, as a role model, has an unpretentious style: two years in succession now she has worn the same outfit to the same commemoration.

After Dan's comment and consulting with my favourite translator and all-round nice person, 朱晓云, I would revise this translation.

西班牙王后做造型真省事：连续两年裙子配饰完全不变参加同一活动

做造型：make style

The Spanish Queen has an unpretentious style: two years in succession now she has worn the same outfit to the same commemoration.

I don't suppose Chinese people care much about what the Spanish Queen wears. I think this was translated from Spanish. If I could see the original text, I would know exactly how to translate it.

Comment: "做造型：function as a (role) model" is a wrong interpretation.

Comment: Quite possible. What is the correct interpretation?

Comment: 做造型 in the context is a common phrase relevant to dressing, makeup, etc as if 'modelling' oneself. Hope I make it clear here.